# Production of Light by Acceleration of Charged Particles

Tags: synchrotron-radiation

I'm reading the Willmott's book titled "An introduction to synchrotron radiation". At pg 55 it is stated:

"The electric-field lines of a charged particle at rest or in uniform motion propagate radially outwards from the particle at the speed of light. Any observer looking at this particle therefore sees no component of the field in any transverse direction. But electromagnetic radiation is a transverse wave, and hence the stationary particle does not
emit light".

This concept is reiterated in the Figure caption:

"A charged particle at rest or moving at uniform speed will not emit light, as any observer of the particle detects no lateral component of the electric-field lines".

I don't understand how this concept relate with the De Broglie expression, defining the wavelength of a photon of a a free electron moving at a constant velocity. From this expression I would expect that an electron moving at a constant velocity would emit photons, hence light. What's the trick?

Comment: What is "the wavelength of a photon of a a free electron"? The de Broglie equation gives us the wavelength of the electron, not of some photon associated with the electron.

Comment: Thanks, you clarified my doubt!